# JHipster Running Client Project

Tags: jhipster

I have created a jhipster client project (yo jhipster --skip-server), my question is how to run or deploy client project.

Answer (score 10):

It's an angular 1 app, so it must be deployed in a web server. In development, `gulp serve` will run your app. For production run `gulp build` then copy the contents of `target/www` folder to your web server. Of course, it still requires a JHipster server application somewhere else.

This option is usually not used by users but rather by JHipster generator itself or by module developers.